# Empty request body using SpringAndroidSpiceRequest

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, robospice

I'm writing an Android app, which is a client to my web application. I'm trying to use RoboSpice to perform network requests.

First of all I decided to test an API call to obtain an OAuth2 token. The following curl command can be called to obtain it from command line:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass" http://testid:testsecret@localhost:8000/oauth2/token/
```

`user` and `pass` are the credentials for a registered user and `testid` and `testsecret` are the id and secret of a registered app in my web application. This call returns a JSON object with a token and other parameters.

I'm trying to do the same request using RoboSpice. Here's the code I wrote for the request:

```java
public class OAuth2Request extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<String> {
    private final String user;
    private final String pass;

    public OAuth2Request(String user, String pass) {
        super(String.class);
        setRestTemplate(new RestTemplate());
        getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws RestClientException {
        String client_id = "testid";
        String client_secret = "testsecret";
        HttpBasicAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(client_id, client_secret);
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
        requestHeaders.setUserAgent("AndroidNotesApp/1.0");

        String data = String.format("grant_type=password&username=%s&password=%s", this.user, this.pass);
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(data, requestHeaders);

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/oauth2/token/";
        return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, requestEntity, String.class);
    }
}
```

The `SpiceManager` in my activity is declared like:

```java
protected SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService.class);
```

and the request is made by the following lines:

```java
OAuth2Request req = new OAuth2Request(user, pass);
spiceManager.execute(req, new OAuth2RequestListener());
```

`user` and `pass` are `String`s, which get their values from `EditText` views.

But when I try to run this request, I get an exception `400 BAD REQUEST`.
I set up logging in my django app to print the requests which come to `/oauth2/token/`, and I see, that POST parameters are empty in this request (I expect them to be the same as during the curl request, something like `{'grant_type': 'password', 'password': 'pass', 'username': 'user'}`).

Why are POST parameters empty in case of RoboSpice request? What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Just in case: the oauth2 authentication in my django web application is implemented using DjangoOAuthToolkit with DjangoRestFramework.

**UPDATE**: I decided to setup nginx proxy before my django web application to log the request body. The request body I get from the Android app is the following:

```
\x22grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass\x22
```

So the strange `\x22` symbol is added in the beginning and in the end of the body (I believe it is a double-quote `"` symbol, but I'm not sure). Seems that these `\x22` screw up POST parameter parsing in django. How can I get rid of these symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, so I'm posting an answer in case it helps someone.

`SpringAndroidSpiceRequest` by default tries to map a java object into JSON, so when I tried to send a `String` in request body, it wrapped it in double quotes to make it a JSON string. I don't need to send a request body as a JSON string, and in order to do that I need to define additional message converters.

Strangely, these lines in constructor don't seem to do anything

```java
setRestTemplate(new RestTemplate());
getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
```

When I used debugger, it showed just one message converter, `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. So I decided to add my own message converters in `loadDataFromNetwork` method.

I needed two message converters: `FormHttpMessageConverter`, which will process request and make a request POST body from `MultiValueMap`, and `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`, which will process the JSON response into `OAuth2Token` POJO, which I also declared.

I believe, that for simple testing of REST API with client (POST plain strings and receive plain strings) it'll be better to choose another implementation for `SpiceRequest` other than `SpringAndroidSpiceRequest`, but I decided to stick with it, as it'll be easier to implement the complete client for my web application.

The complete code for `OAuth2Request`:

```java
public class OAuth2Request extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<OAuth2Token> {
    private final String user;
    private final String pass;

    public OAuth2Request(String user, String pass) {
        super(OAuth2Token.class);

        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Token loadDataFromNetwork() throws RestClientException {
        String client_id = "testid";
        String client_secret = "testsecret";
        HttpBasicAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(client_id, client_secret);
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
        requestHeaders.setUserAgent("AndroidNotesApp/1.0");

        MultiValueMap<String, String> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        data.add("grant_type", "password");
        data.add("username", this.user);
        data.add("password", this.pass);
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(data, requestHeaders);

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/oauth2/token/";

        getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().clear();
        getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, requestEntity, OAuth2Token.class);
    }
}
```